# Makefile header includes

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am developing a Makefile for an old project. The new Makefile is based on an older one I used successfully with other projects, but now I face an odd problem.

My project has the following form:

```
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── folder1
    │   ├── somefiles.c
    │   └── somefiles.h
    ├── folder2
    │   ├── problematic.h
    │   ├── somefiles.c
    │   ├── somefiles.h
    │   └── subdir
    │       └── included_file.h
    └── folder3
        ├── somefiles.c
        └── somefiles.h
```

My Makefile has the following line:

```
LIBRARY_INC_PATHS     = $(addprefix -I, $(shell find . -name '*.h' -printf '"%h"\n' | sort -u))
```

In file `problematic.h` there is the line:

```
#include "subdir/included_file.h"
```

Which causes trouble. GCC says that there is no such file or directory.

If I change it to:

```
#include "included_file.h"
```

the problem vanishes, but this is not an acceptable solution in my case.

What modifications should I make to my makefile so I can include files from my C code using relative paths, instead of their name only?

Comment: How many folders do you have? Would it be too much of an effort to just explicitly name the include directories instead of that find call?

Comment: Yes, the actual project has a few dozen files. Its quite impractical to state all the directories explicitly.

Comment: My reasoning is this: how often does that list of directories change? If changes are unlikely or only occur seldom then you might be over engineering this ;)

Comment: To be honest drastic changes (that require the whole list to be changed, not a simple addition), are quite unlikely to happen. So it seems more than an one-off effort, and you are possibly right. But now it is mostly a curiosity thing, why something so obvious (for me) does not work?

Comment: Hmm, indeed. `src/folder2` should be part of the result of that `find`, right? (Because it contains other header files) then why isn't GCC finding the file...

Comment: Correct. I have cross-checked that the command output contains both `-Isrc/folder2` & `-Isrc/folder2/subdir`.

Comment: I am actually confused. Relative headers should work regardless of what `-I...` flags you pass into the compiler, unless your `problematic.h` has some soft/hard links pointing to it from different locations, where `subdir` does not exist and you include *that* by accident.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. If I use `-Isrc/folder2`, it works. (I am using gcc 4.2.1)

Comment: Suggest generating dependency files, `#include` those dependency files in the makefile (similar to: `ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif`  and use a compile recipe that looks similar to: `%.o:%.c %.d ....`